# YoutubePlayerSupportFragment gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api

I Want to use `YoutubePlayerSupportFragment` in my application for playing youtube video but it gives following exception :

```
01-08 14:52:11.953: E/AndroidRuntime(4069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 14:52:11.953: E/AndroidRuntime(4069): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 14:52:11.953: E/AndroidRuntime(4069):     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onStart(Unknown Source)
01-08 14:52:11.953: E/AndroidRuntime(4069):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1524)
01-08 14:52:11.953: E/AndroidRuntime(4069):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:957)
01-08 14:52:11.953: E/AndroidRuntime(4069):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
```

I am using the following logic to replace my fragment :

```
 Fragment fragment=new EditBloop();
 final FragmentTransaction ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
 ft1.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "edit"); 
 ft1.commit();
```

My Fragment class is as follows :

```
public class EditBloop extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment 
  {
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle               savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_bloop, null);

 }
```

and My xml edit_bloop :

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

So, please guide me How solve this ?

Comment: When the error is being thrown? Right after you're trying to replace the fragment?

Comment: On a side note you should use the container as viewgroup instead of null when you inflate and set last parameter to false. Like following: inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_bloop, container, false);

Comment: @Warpzit  Thankyou, but its not working

Comment: @koti it was a side note on how you should inflate fragments properly. It wasn't the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getSupportFragmentManager()`, like so:

```
EditBloop fragment = EditBloop.newInstance("edit");
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```